# showing image in listview with json

Tags: java, android, json

I write program to get data(text) from json and show it in list view , i write the code and its working but now i get url of image with json but i dont know how to show the image in list view with image view , please help me

here is my code

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pd;
JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> P;
JSONArray s=null;
private final String url="http://192.168.1.4:81/upload/travel.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
P = new ArrayList<>();
new travel().execute();

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
String id_code=((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.id_code)).getText().toString();
Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ADD.class);
in.putExtra("id",id_code);
startActivity(in);

}

class travel extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pd.setMessage("login");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    List<NameValuePair> parms=new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject json=jParser.makeHTTPRequest(url,"GET");

    try {
        int t=json.getInt("t");
        if(t==1){
            s=json.getJSONArray("travel");
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                JSONObject c=s.getJSONObject(i);
                String id=c.getString("id");
                String companyname=c.getString("companyname");
                String cod=c.getString("cod");
                String bign=c.getString("bign");
                String stop=c.getString("stop");
                String date=c.getString("date");
                String time=c.getString("time");
                String price=c.getString("price");
                String url_image=c.getString("url_image");

                HashMap<String,String>map=new HashMap<String,String>();
                map.put("id",id);
                map.put("companyname",companyname);
                map.put("cod",cod);
                map.put("bign",bign);
                map.put("stop",stop);
                map.put("date",date);
                map.put("time",time);
                map.put("price",price);
                map.put("url_image",url_image);

                P.add(map);

            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    pd.dismiss();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, P, R.layout.item_list,
                    new String[]{"url_image","companyname", "cod", "bign", "stop", "date", "time", "price"},
                    new int[]{R.id.id_code,R.id.companyname, R.id.cod, R.id.bign, R.id.stop, R.id.date, R.id.time1, R.id.price});


            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

}

}
}
```

Comment: This might be useful: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: no i dont want to use picasso library

Comment: you should create a custom listview adapter

Comment: Why you dont want to go with Picasso?

Comment: Agreed... Why not go with Picasso? Looks like the way to go

Comment: maybe he want learn something !!